# How to count the number of days in a given month in a given year in R

Tags: r

I would like to count the number of days where the variable is superior to 50.
I have a simple data frame like this:

```
            year month day variable
            1990 01    1   25
            1990 01    2   50
            1990 01    3   52
             ...
            1990 12    31  10
            1991 01    1   53
            1991 01    2   20
            ...
```

I already could subset a dataframe where the variable is superior to 50:

```
v50 <- subset(data,data$variable > 50)
```

But after I do not know how to create a new dataframe showing the number of day where the variable is superior to 50 (v50), in each month for every year, like:

```
year month v50
1990 01    2
1990 02    5
...
1991 01    2
```

Thank you for any help or support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already have the `subset` of the dataframe you want, you now want to read the number of rows each `year` , `month` pair has so I think `table` should work here

```
table(v50$year, v50$month)
```